# How can I update only one field from MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

I have module name Items. My module looks like this:

```
{
_id: 4874874874848,
name: Item1
data: {name: 'Item name', id:1235}
}
```

And Now I need to change only what is inside the data array (name and id).
I have been using Items.FindOneAndUpdate() but I need to inset new data in that data array. My question is, how can I add new values but only in data array in my module. 
My database should look like this:

```
    {
        _id: 4874874874848,
        name: Item1
        data: {
        0{name: 'Item name', id:1235}
        1{name: 'Item name1', id:44545}
        2{name: 'Item name2', id:54545}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need `$addToSet` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Though note that this won't add any values that would be duplicates

Edit, adding example:

```
'$addToSet': { data: {
    '$each': [
        {name: 'Item name1', id:44545},
        {name: 'Item name2', id:54545}
    ]
}}
```

Comment: That doesnt work form me. I need somehow to update only this field 1{name: 'Item name1', id:44545} in my database.

Comment: It only works when I create that field for the first time. But when I'm up to update it, It doesnt work.

Comment: The update would look like this:
`'$addToSet': { data: { '$each': [ {name: 'Item name1', id:44545}, {name: 'Item name2', id:54545} ] }} `
You'd need the existing `data` element in the document to be an array though, looks like from what you've posted above that it's actually an object at the moment, in which case you'd need to convert it over to an array to start with.

The update I've given above will either create `data` with the items given, or add the new items to an existing array